# How to deploy contracts when approved by a DAO

Tags: contract-deployment, multisignature, dao

Here's the flow I'm hoping to achieve:

1. Member proposes a contract to be deployed, including source code.
2. DAO votes on whether or not the contract should be deployed.
3. If the vote is approved the contract is deployed.

In my ideal world, this is all managed on-chain.

For my purposes, the DAO uses [Aragon](https://aragon.org) and owns a [Gnosis multisig](https://gnosis-safe.io).

This is the closest flow I can imagine at this point.

1. Member/Leadership submits [create/create2](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/libraries/CreateCall.sol) contract transaction request through Gnosis.
2. Member/Leadership submits proposal to DAO to execute the transaction.
3. If approved, the remaining multisig owners sign and confirm the transaction.

Does this sound like a suitable flow?
It feels like there is a disconnect between the DAO and Gnosis deployment, where a there is no guarantee the proposal was accepted. Is there a way to close this gap?

Comment: Compound's Governor Alpha is the most used contract for on-chain governance. www.tally.xyz is a platform that offers a UI to vote/make proposals. No need to go through a multisig this way

Comment: Thanks, @0xSanson! I completely missed this feature. Looks like Aragon has a similar feature.

Comment: Hey @Milk did you find the correct way? I had the same question, share any resources.